# nodejs error: module.js:340 throw err;

Tags: node.js

I tried to run a sample server but I got error message on Windows. Then I tried to run it on my friend's machine, but it just went well, windows system too. I don't know what's happening.
Let me show the source code and the error message:
source code:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("Hello World");
response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

output:

```
D:\test>node server.js

module.js:340
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\test\server.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3
```

Ps: **server.js** is the file to execute.

Comment: check if `server.js` is name of the file you are executing. you are mentioning it wrong.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh sorry about that, **server.js** is the file I'm executing.

Comment: your server.js is not present in test folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you are mentioning is appearing because, you are trying to execute a file that is not there.

Check if your **D:\test** folder has a file named **server.js** with the code you have quoted above.

I suggest you to check whether **server.js** is in your current folder from the console by typing `dir` command, before you go for `node server.js`

Comment: I'm sure there is a file name **server.js** in **D:\test** because I created them by myself. The source code is writen in **server.js**. I execute **server.js** via Command Line Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is happening because you should check execution path like

you need to go on **D:/ Drive** and check there is **test folder is exist or not** if the file exists then you should check **there are server.js or not** and you find there is **no server.js on test folder** that's why this happening.

so if you want to execute that script you need to go where the **file is exist**