# Cordova build fails

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, command-line-interface

When i run cordova run android cli it gives me this error. I am unable to find the solution on internet. cli.js is present in the src folder. I don't know what is causing the problem.

Thanks in advance

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
   ^

Error: Cannot find module '../src/cli'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
   at require (module.js:385:17)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\App Metrik-   Designer\AppData\Roaming\npm\cor
 dova:40:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nodejs error: module.js:340 throw err;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988934/nodejs-error-module-js340-throw-err)

Comment: cli.js is present in the folder.

Comment: Maybe your relative path isn't correct

Comment: I had a similar error when I updated cordova, but I clone de projet again and it works fine.